# take comparison operator as a char with scanf and use in if

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    char c;

    printf("Enter value for a and b ");
    scanf("%d %d ",a,b);
    printf("Enter c(<) or c(>) for comparison");
    scanf(" %c ",c);

    if(a ? b)
    {
        printf("%d ",a);
    }
}
```

I want to take char c from scanf and put it place of ? ,and I want to run if statement in this manner,in any way is it possible?

Comment: What doesn't work in your code? What duh heck's `a ? b` anyway?

Comment: Why can't you write one more `if` statement like `if (c == '<') {...} else {...} `?

Comment: `if ( c == '<' )`? Maybe you better first consult a C book, basic programming tutorial, or similar?

Comment: `scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);`, `scanf(" %c", &c);`

Comment: @Dima actually in my principal code there are two integer and two strings;   I have to compare all these information with given information which has two integer two strings and 4 comparison operator for each so it seemed hard to write one more statement for each

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do something like this is C, to dynamically change the comparison operator at runtime.

Instead, you could use an approach as presented below (I also added a few fixes to the code, explained in comments):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char c;

    printf("Enter value for a and b ");
    // No spaces neeeded after specifiers, otherwise the user have to input additional data
    // Pointers to the variables have to be passed to scanf
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("Enter c(<) or c(>) for comparison ");
    // A single space needed before %c , to discard previous newline
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    int condition = 0; // initial: false
    // For every of the operators, assign the comparison result to 'condition'
    if (c == '<')
        condition = (a < b);
    else if (c == '>')
        condition = (a > b);
    else
        printf("Unknown operator: %c\n", c);

    // Test for condition
    if (condition)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a);
    }
    // Add a return statement
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** as Weather Vane noticed, this variant is only for `c++`, not `c`.

You can try to do something like that

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;    

class Compare {
    public: 
    virtual bool compare (int a, int b) = 0;
};

class Less: public Compare {
    public: 
    bool compare (int a, int b) {
        return a < b;
    }
};

class More: public Compare {
    public: 
    bool compare (int a, int b) {
        return a > b;
    }
};

map<char, Compare*> m;

int main() {
    m['<'] = new Less();
    m['>'] = new More();

    int a, b;
    char c;
    printf("Enter value for a and b ");
    scanf("%d %d ", &a, &b);
    printf("Enter c(<) or c(>) for comparison");
    scanf(" %c ", &c);

    if ((*m[c]).compare(a, b)) {
        printf("%d ", a);
    } else {
        printf("%d ", b); 
    }
}
```

PS sorry for `using namespace std` and `include <bits/stdc++.h>` but I didn't want to think about stuff like `std::` and a lot of `include`'s)

Comment: @WeatherVane oops. My bad, did not notice, sorry